# Klockwork scan c++ Template value

Tags: c++, klocwork

```
 > -Severity (Error)
 > -ID(local): 1
 > -Code: UNINIT.CTOR.MUST --> IPCAtomic()
 > -Message: 'this->value' is not initialized in this constructor.
 > -Details:
 > 
 > 'this->value' is not initialized in this constructor.
 > 
 > * CommunicationTypes.h:198: 'this->value' is used, but is
 > uninitialized.
 > 
 > * CommunicationTypes.h:198: List of instantiations (may be
 > incomplete)
 > 
 > * CommunicationTypes.h:198: <anonymous>::IPCAtomic< ,
 > >::#constructor
 > 
 > Current status 'Analyze'
```

This is the code I have, I also tried other options, but KW still produces the same error

```
     template <typename T, typename SerializeAs = T>
class IPCAtomic : public IPCBundleIfc
{
    typedef IPCAtomic<T, SerializeAs> MyType;
public:
    T value;

    IPCAtomic() : value(T())
    {
    }

    IPCAtomic(T v) : value(v)
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_base_of<IPCBundleIfc, T>::value, "type parameter of this class can not derive from IPCBundleIfc");
    }

    virtual ~IPCAtomic() {}

    operator T& ()
    {
        return value;
    }

    MyType& operator=(const T& v)
    {
        if (&v != &value)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const T& v) const
    {
        return value == v;
    }

    bool operator==(const MyType& v) const
    {
        return value == v.value;
    }
```

Can you offer any solutions?

Comment: Is there anywhere a code path that will try to invoke a copy constructor? I don't see an implementation for that.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I added some code

Comment: I also have the "slight" disadvantage that I don't have clockwork installed (or available) ;) And I can't spot anything really wrong right away. I usually initialize template members like value differently though, I would use : IPCAtomic() : value{} for default initialization.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I tried it, it also failed

Comment: Clang tidy doesn't detect anything wrong with that code (but then again I think it checks less). So for the moment I am out of ideas

Comment: @PepijnKramer your answer of IPCAtomic() : value{}  worked, you can answer this and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize templated member values, use list initialization instead of initializing from a default constructed object.

Like this :

```
IPCAtomic() : 
    value{}
{
}

// when initializing with a value use const T& this avoids 
// unecessary copies. Also make constructors with one parameter
// explicit so they can't accidentaly be used as type conversions.
explicit IPCAtomic(const T& v) : 
    value{v}
{
}

// allow efficient initialization from temporaries
explicit IPCAtomic(T&& v) : 
   value{v}
{
}
```